# Add countries in form field Prestashop 1.7.x

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to display a dropdown with all the countries that prestashop has in his database.
When a customer is adding a new address, a field ask for the country, but displays only United States.

[image: ask1]

How can I make to display all the countries?
Because when I edit the customer I can see all the countries.

[image: ask2]

**What I have tried:**

In the location: `/public_html/Project/themes/myTemplate/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl`

I realized there is a Foreach to fill the dropdown, but load United States.

```
{elseif $field.type === 'countrySelect'}

{block name='form_field_item_country'}
  <select
  class="custom-select js-country"
  name="{$field.name}"
  {if $field.required}required{/if}
  >
    <option value disabled selected>{$field.label}</option>
    {foreach from=$field.availableValues item="label" key="value"}
      <option value="{$value}" {if $value eq $field.value} selected {/if}>{$label}</option>
    {/foreach}
  </select>
{/block}
```

I can see in console, actually, loads one value only.

[image: ask3]

Could anybody has the same error?
How can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in **International > Locations** , check **Countries** tab  and make sure the other countries are active (they aren't in a standard US / UK Prestashop installation)

Comment: Thanks it works for me, Going to **International (tag) -> geographic locations -> Countries** also there I can add or remove fields. Have a great day!